# How to sort my list on basis of date field

Tags: java, android, sorting, date, listview

I have a list of 97 elements that i need to sot on basis of date which contains dates of format DD/MM/YYYY which is in string type only, null objects and objects of String type also, i.e. it has elements such as

**Example of data in my date field :**

```
12/02/2014
11/07/2017
null
India
```

Now I want to sort the elements of my list based on date field.

what i want is that all the entries with date should apear first in ascending order then all the entries with strings such as india then entries with null in date field then entries with empty date field, so how should i code it in compareTo method

I have seen a lot of examples on that but not getting the desired result.
How to do that?Help me please?

**`ListAdapter.java`**

```
public class ListAdapter1 extends BaseAdapter {
static int c=0;
    Context context;
    List<ListViewRow> l=new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> lv=new ArrayList<String>();
    ListAdapter1(Context context, String[] getid,String name[], String[] email, String[] mobile, String[] pass, String[] date) {
this.context=context;



        for(int i=0;i<getid.length;i++)
        {

            l.add(new ListViewRow(getid[i],name[i],email[i],mobile[i],pass[i],date[i]));
        }


        Collections.sort(l, new ListRowComparator());

    }




    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return l.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_row, parent, false);
        TextView textView1 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView textView2 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.email);
        TextView textView3 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.mobile);
        TextView textView4 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.pass);
        TextView textView5 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.date);

ListViewRow lvr=l.get(position);

    textView1.setText(lvr.name);
    textView2.setText(lvr.email);
    textView3.setText(lvr.mobile);
    textView4.setText(lvr.pass);
        textView5.setText(lvr.date);


        return rowView;

    }
}
```

**`ListViewRow.java`**

```
public class ListViewRow  {

    String getid,name,email,mobile,pass,date;

    ListViewRow( String getid, String name, String email, String mobile, String pass, String date)
    {

        this.getid = getid;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.mobile = mobile;
        this.pass = pass;
        this.date= date;
    }


}
```

**`ListRowComparator.java`**

```
public class ListRowComparator implements Comparator<ListViewRow> {
    @Override
    public int compare(ListViewRow o1, ListViewRow o2) {

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

        int compareResult = 0;
        try {
            if (o1.date== null || o2.date== null)
            {
                return 0;
            }

        else {
                compareResult = format.parse(o1.date).compareTo(format.parse(o2.date));
                System.out.println("compare:" + compareResult);
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return compareResult;
    }
}
```

Comment: change `new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");` to `new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");`

Comment: @chandil03 agree.

Answer (score 0):

First change

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

with

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Second don't return 0

```
if (o1.date== null || o2.date== null)
{
    return 0;
}
```

`return 0;` means `o1.date == o2.date`

Instead you can throw an exception, or set a default date.

UPDATE:

I hope that's what you mean. `valid date > string > null > ""` if not just change the value;

```
public class ListRowComparator implements Comparator<ListViewRow> {
    private final SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    private final int VALID_DATE = 4;
    private final int STRING_DATE = 3;
    private final int NULL_DATE = 2;
    private final int EMPTY_DATE = 1;

    private int priorityLevel(String date){
        if (date == null) return NULL_DATE;
        if (date.equals("")) return EMPTY_DATE;

        try {
            format.parse(date);
            return VALID_DATE;
        } catch (ParseException e){
            return STRING_DATE;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(ListViewRow o1, ListViewRow o2) {
        int o1Priority = priorityLevel(o1.date);
        int o2Priority = priorityLevel(o2.date);

        if (o1Priority == VALID_DATE && o2Priority == VALID_DATE){
            try {
                return format.parse(o1.date).compareTo(format.parse(o2.date));
            } catch (ParseException e){
                // unreachable code
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (o1Priority == STRING_DATE && o2Priority == STRING_DATE){
            return o1.date.compareTo(o2.date);
        }

        // else 
        return o1Priority - o2Priority;
    }
}
```

Comment: what i want is that all the entries with date should apear first  in ascending order then all the entries with strings such as india then entries with null in date field then entries with  empty date field, so how should i code it in compareTo method

Comment: @Ankit I have updated my answer, hope that's what you want

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

```
private class ListRowComparator implements Comparator<ListViewRow> {
    private Date date1;
    private Date date2;

    @Override
    public int compare(ListViewRow o1, ListViewRow o2) {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            if (o1.date == null) o1.date = "01/01/1900";
            date1 = format.parse(o1.date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            try {
                date1 = format.parse("01/01/1900");
            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            if (o2.date == null) o2.date = "01/01/1900";
            date2 = format.parse(o2.date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            try {
                date2 = format.parse("01/01/1900");
            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return date1.compareTo(date2);
    }
}
```

Comment: but you are taking String data type in Comparator so it will only sort the date field but for other field